# React Native Paper Radio Button onPress event not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-paper

For some reason my onPress event is not working with React Native Paper RadioButton. I have follow instructions per docs I believe

not working:

```
<RadioButton.Item
                    label={item.templateName}
                    value={item._ref}
                    mode="android"
                    position="leading"
                    labelStyle={{textAlign: 'left'}}
                    onPress={()=> setValue('something')}
                  />
```

working however if I use set state the page will render to much

```
<RadioButton.Item
                    label={item.templateName}
                    value={item._ref}
                    mode="android"
                    position="leading"
                    labelStyle={{textAlign: 'left'}}
                    onPress={setValue('something')}
                  />
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this might be useful for you. Please keep below code in your file.

import this : `import { RadioButton } from 'react-native-paper';`

`const [value, setValue] = React.useState('first');`

Then keep radio buttons in group tab like below:

```
<RadioButton.Group onValueChange={value => setValue(value)} value={value}>
  <RadioButton.Item label="First item" value="first" />
  <RadioButton.Item label="Second item" value="second" />
</RadioButton.Group>
```